# A variant of transfer learning

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning

Suppose we want to train $K$ linear classifiers based on iid samples. Each classifier is of the form
$x\mapsto\mathrm{sign}(w\cdot x+\theta)$, with the constraint that the hyperplane $w$ is the same for all of the classifiers, but the thresholds $\theta$ can all be different. The motivation for this problem comes from *transfer learning*: we want to train a model of loan approval decisions where the lenders share a common decision procedure ($w$) but differ in their risk thresholds ($\theta$) --- and we wish to pool the samples so as to increase the statistical significance of the common $w$.

We model this as follows.
Each loan applicant is modeled as a point in $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}^d$, represented by its feature vector.
Each lender's decision regarding an applicant
is a
signed
bit $y\in\mathcal{Y}:=\{-1,1\}$.
The $K$ lenders will be indexed by
$k\in[K]:=\{1,\ldots,K\}$.
Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a distribution over
$\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\times[K]$.
Thus, a randomly drawn triple
$(X,Y,\kappa)\sim\mathcal{D}$ corresponds to the
decision $Y$ regarding applicant $X$ by
lender $\kappa$.

We consider the usual SVM hinge loss
incurred by $(w,\theta)$ on a labeled point
$(x,y)\in\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$:
$$
\ell(w,\theta;x,y)
=
\max\{0,1-y(w\cdot x+\theta)\}
.
$$

On a sample of $n$ labeled triples
$(X_i,Y_i,\kappa_i)$, we define the sample risk
of the classifier defined by
$(w,\theta_1,\theta_2,\ldots,\theta_K)$
by
$$
R =
\sum_{i=1}^n
\sum_{k=1}^K
1[\kappa_i=k]
\ell(w,\theta_k;X_i,Y_i).
$$
As usual, we regularize this loss by the norm
of $w$, so the expression we'll be minimizing is
$$
L=
R+\lambda||w||^2,
$$
where $\lambda>0$ is a regularization parameter to be tuned via cross-validation. Minimizing $L$ is a convex (in fact, quadratic) program, which can be accomplished via SGD.

The Rademacher-based generalization bounds for this classifier class are straightforward to work out. (Spoiler alert: It's of order $O(\Theta\sqrt{K/n})$,
where $\Theta=||w||\cdot\max_{i\in[n]}||X_i||$.)

Question: Has a similar model of transfer learning appeared in the literature?